# Could not cast value of type 'UIImageView' (0x17c0f5c) to 'UIButton' (0x17c3298)

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to reset the board of my tic tac toe game but I get this error if I change i to 1 in my for loop everything works fine.I also changed the tag of my label, button and view from 0 to 20 but still i get this error. This is the code

```
var activePlayer = 1

    var gameActive = true
    var gameState = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  // board is empty
    var winningCombinations = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]]


    @IBOutlet var playAgainButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var gameOverLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func playAgainPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

         activePlayer = 1
         gameActive = true
        gameState = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

        var button : UIButton
        //resetting the image of the button
        for var i = 0; i < 9; i++ {

            button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
            button.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
        }


        gameOverLabel.hidden = true
        playAgainButton.hidden = true
        gameOverLabel.center = CGPointMake(gameOverLabel.center.x - 400, gameOverLabel.center.y)
        playAgainButton.center = CGPointMake(playAgainButton.center.x - 400, playAgainButton.center.y)


    }
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        if gameState[sender.tag] == 0 && gameActive == true{
        var image = UIImage()
        // updating board

        gameState[sender.tag] = activePlayer

        if activePlayer == 1 {

         image = UIImage(named: "nought.png")!
       activePlayer = 2

        } else {
             image = UIImage(named: "cross.png")!
            activePlayer = 1

        }
               // to access the tag of the image pressed use sender.tag
            sender.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)


            for combination in winningCombinations {


                if gameState[combination[0]] != 0  && gameState[combination[0]] == gameState[combination[1]] && gameState[combination[1]] == gameState[combination[2]]{

                    var labelText = "Noughts have won!"

                    if gameState[combination[0]] == 2{
                        labelText = "Crosses have won"
                    }
                    gameOverLabel.text = labelText

                    gameOverLabel.hidden = false
                    playAgainButton.hidden = false


                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
                        self.gameOverLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.gameOverLabel.center.x + 400, self.gameOverLabel.center.y)
                        self.playAgainButton.center = CGPointMake(self.playAgainButton.center.x + 400, self.playAgainButton.center.y)


                    })
                    gameActive = false
                }
            }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved. The way i did it was that i moved my button with 0 tag after my board.

Answer (score 1):

Check your storyboard - there must be an `UIImageView` with a tag equal to `i`. View tags are supposed to be unique, though there is no mechanism to enforce this - this is something you need to take care of yourself.

The usefulness of tags is limited; you're better of using `IBOutlet`s in most cases.

If you want to stick with tags, embed your `UIButton`s in an `@IBOutlet UIView buttonContainerView`, and replace

```
for var i = 0; i < 9; i++ {
    button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
    button.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
}
```

with

```
for subview in buttonContainerView.subviews as! UIView {
    if let button = view as? UIButton {
        button.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave them each unique tags. When i change my for loop to                         for var i = 1; i < 9; i++ {

            button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
            button.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
        } it resets my board except the one button that has a tag of 0. The one with tag 0 has the problem

Comment: I see you edited your code - i starts now with 0 instead of 1. As 0 is the default value for `UIView.tag`, view.viewWithTag(i) can return almost all subviews.

Comment: but all the sub view tags are non zero

Comment: That could be, but the `viewWithTag` function traverses the entire view hierarchy - not only the direct subviews, but also the subviews of those and so on. All `UIButton`s have an `UIImageView`s underneath, so I think the method picks up one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the storyboard and in view move your zero tag button above all other buttons. If it does not work, move it up again, so it is the first item in the hierarchy in view. This should allow the code to find the zero tag button first, before finding something else with zero tag.